# Which function seems to be matching on multiple values in data frames

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I'm trying to write an R script that indicates what hours/minutes in the day "fall into" a specific start/end time.

So, for example a class with a start/end time of 8 - 8:30 am, would "fall into" 8:00, 8:05, 8:10...8:30. And would not fall into other times.

The end goal would be a data frame with the first column as the start time, the second column, the end time, and the third column the individual time that "falls into" the start/end times. E.g.:

start    end    time
8:00     8:30   8:00
8:00     8:30   8:05
8:00     8:30   8:10

Here's my current script:

```
library("tidyverse")

#create initial matrix
vector1 <- c(1:24) #listing of hours
vector2 <- seq.int(.05,.60,.05) #listing of every 5 minutes
possible_hrs <- data.frame(outer(vector1,vector2,'+')) 
#matrix of all possible hours/minutes

#pull in start/end time possibilities
start <-c(5,5.30)
end <-c(8,9.55)
class_time<-data.frame(start,end)


times<-function(class_time,possible_hrs){

#extract the values that match; where possible hours "fall into" start/end times
match = which(possible_hrs >= class_time$start & possible_hrs <= class_time$end, arr.ind=TRUE) 

values = data.frame(sort(possible_hrs[match]))

starts <- class_time$start
ends <- class_time$end
times <- values

results<-data.frame(starts,ends,times)
}

  results2 <- times(class_time,possible_hrs)
  results2
```

But something is going wrong with the which() function as I'm getting values that shouldn't "fall in" the start/end times respectively.

So the time 8:05 shouldn't fall into 5:00 - 8:00 time block. And likewise I'm not getting all of the results in the second time block...I'm not getting a time of 9:00 that should fall into the 8:00 - 9:55 time block.

Comment: I think there is recycling of 'start' and 'end' values.  You may need to do this separately `Map(function(x, y) possible_hrs >= x & possible_hrs <= end, class_time$start, class_time$end)`

Comment: @akrun, Thanks. I think that got me a little closer, but still not 100%. Here is a snapshot of the results:` [[1]]
         X1   ....   X12
 [4,] FALSE.... FALSE
 [5,]  TRUE ....TRUE
...
 [8,]  TRUE ....TRUE
 [9,] FALSE .... FALSE `

Where x1 is the 5:00 position and x12 is 5:60 (5:59). So the first example should run from 5:00 am - 8:00 am, but it goes all the way to 8:59. This first time block is 5:00 - 8:00.

The second result [[2]] starts at the x6 position or 5:30 (which is correct), but again goes to 8:59 when it should go to 9:55. The second time block is then 5:30 to 9:55.